# How do I set up a PostgreSQL database for use with PostGIS and GeoDjango?

Tags: python, postgis, database, geodjango, django

[The Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/gis/tutorial/#setting-up) say to use

```
createdb -T template_postgis geodjango
```

but I already have a database set up. While trying to find out what this actually does and a way to apply it to an existing database, I found this on [postgis.net](http://postgis.net/install/):

```
-- Enable PostGIS (includes raster)
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
-- Enable Topology
CREATE EXTENSION postgis_topology;
-- fuzzy matching needed for Tiger
CREATE EXTENSION fuzzystrmatch;
-- Enable US Tiger Geocoder
CREATE EXTENSION postgis_tiger_geocoder;
```

In trying to figure out what Tiger is, I found this in [the postgis docs](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.1/postgis_installation.html#create_new_db_extensions):

```
psql -d [yourdatabase] -c "CREATE EXTENSION postgis;"
Topology is packaged as a separate extension and installable with command:
psql -d [yourdatabase] -c "CREATE EXTENSION postgis_topology;"
```

How do I ready my current Django database for use with PostGIS and GeoDjango?

I'm using Django 1.8 and PostgreSQL 9.4.

Comment: What do you want to know? That's all. Go to your db and create those extensions, then you will be able to connect this db in settings.py

Comment: What does creating a database with template_postgis do? And what are fuzzystrmatch and postgis_tiger_geocoder for?

Comment: Template did exactly the same as create extensions, it was only way to create postgis, but now `create extensions postgis;` is recommended. I guess the tiger extensions are for tiger data support: https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/tiger.html

Comment: If you already have a db, you can use migrate.py from geodjango to register them